# How to move one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller after loading progressbar in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

Hi I am beginner in iOS in my project I am using progress bar

And here my main requirement I want load progress bar up-to 5 seconds after completing that progress bar loading I want to move another view controller for this I have used some code but not working please help me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
    self.progressView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.progressView];

  self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateUI:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}

- (void)updateUI:(NSTimer *)timer
{
self.progressView.progress += 0.5;

    ContactVC*VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: You put repeats = YES. So timer always fire again and again. If you want to stop that timer and move to next viewcontroller then you have to put some condition. Like , timer should be stop after some time and so that you need to make timer invalidate and after invalidate you have to push another view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
    progressView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:progressView];

   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateUI:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateUI:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    progressView.progress += 0.5/10;

    if ((int)progressView.progress) {

        [myTimer invalidate];

    Demoview*VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Demoview"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this method:

```
- (void)updateUI:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.progressView.progress += 0.5/100;//because this limit is [0-1]. So, you have divide each progress unit by 100 in order to show percentage progress. 
    NSLog(@"%f",self.progressView.progress);
     if ((int)self.progressView.progress) {
       NSLog(@"Call View");
       [self.myTimer invalidate];
       self.myTimer = nil;//so that timer not fire again
       ContactVC *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContactVC"];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
}
}
```